# Check if number is divisible by 2, if yes, print the number

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Well, here is a piece of my ASM code:

```
    MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
    MOV AL,[myNum] ;move the inputed number to AL
    DIV two ;div 123 / 2;
    CMP AH,0
    JNE inputIsPrime

    ;If 123 % 2 = 0, output 123 / 2.
    DIV ten
    MOV DH,AH

    SUB AL,'0'
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21h

    MOV divisionCalc,DH

    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,DH
    INT 21h
    JMP endProg
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is, after I write "60" to keyboard and press enter, I get the wrong output. I want to get the number "30" because 60/2 = 30.
If I enter 42, I want to get 21 as output.

Any ideas why my code fails?

Here's the full code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA

DisplayString DB 'Enter number up to 120:', 13,10,'$'
isPrimeNum DB 'is prime', 13,10,'$'
    goodMSG DB 'good', 13,10,'$'
        badMSG DB 'bad', 13,10,'$'
divisionCalc DB ?
myNum DB ?
two DB 2
three DB 3
five DB 5
seven DB 7
ten DB 10
eleven DB 11

    .CODE
Begin:
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV AH,9
    MOV DX,OFFSET DisplayString
    INT 21h

    MOV BL,0 ; Initialize BL to zero!

    ; //READ 3 DIGITS // ;
    ;read first digit for e.g. '1'
    MOV ah,1h
    INT 21h ;read into AL
    SUB AL,30h ; Convert the digit from ASCII to DECIMAL
    MOV myNum,AL

    MOV AH,1
    INT 21h

    CMP AL,13 ;is it Enter?
    JE endInput
    SUB AL,'0' ;Not enter, let's save this new char
    MOV CL, AL ; we save the 2nd char to CL
    MOV AL, myNum ; lets move our first char to AL
    MUL Ten ; multiply by 10 the first char
    MOV myNum,AL ;move that to myNum
    ADD myNum,CL ; add to AL the 2nd char.

    MOV AH,1
    INT 21h

    CMP AL,13 ; is it enter?
    JE endInput
    SUB AL,'0' ;Not enter, let's save this new char
    MOV CL, AL ; we save the 2nd char to CL
    MOV AL, myNum ; lets move our first char to AL
    MUL Ten ; multiply by 10 the first char
    MOV myNum,AL ;move that to myNum
    ADD myNum,CL ; add to AL the 2nd char.

    mov AH,1 ; if the number is 3 chars then this will be the enter now. 
    int 21h 

    ; // FINISH READING 3 DIGITS // ;
    endInput:

            ; AL = AX / two
        ; AH = AX % two
MOV AH, 0 ;reset AH before division
MOV AL,myNum ;move the inputed number to AL
DIV two ;div 123 / 2;
CMP AH,0
JNE inputIsPrime

;If 123 % 2 = 0, output 123 / 2.
DIV ten
MOV DH,AH

SUB AL,'0'
MOV AH,2
MOV DL, AL
INT 21h

MOV divisionCalc,DH

MOV AH,2
MOV DL,DH
INT 21h
JMP endProg

inputIsPrime:
MOV AH,9
MOV DX,OFFSET isPrimeNum
INT 21h

endProg:
MOV AH,4Ch
INT 21h
END Begin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to divide by two, is to right shift the value for a single bit
the bit shiftet will be stored in the carry flag

so

```
shr AX,1
jnc isDividable    ; no carry set = there was no division "rest"
```

will check if AX is divisable by 2

Comment: Tommy But how can I print 30? if 60 / 2 = 30. The language allows me to print one char at a time. so I divide 30 by 10, and store 3 to AL, and 0 to AH. but it still won't work. I don't want to use the carry flag because I took care of the logic if it is divisable by 2. I want to take care of the printing problem only.

Comment: check your other question ;)

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way to test for an even number is to test the low bit:

```
test    AL,1
jz   isEven
```

This is non-destructive, and will macro-fuse into a single test-and-branch uop on modern CPUs.

In this case, where you want the result of the division by 2 so you can print it, then the shift is a good way.  See Tommy's answer.

There are other use-cases for shifting by one to shift a bit out into `CF`: e.g. looping over the bits in an integer.